# Why I can not ssh to my Vagrant host? vagrant@192.168.1.8: Permission denied (publickey)

Tags: ssh, ssh-keys

I created 5 VMs for my project
vagrant status

```
Current machine states:

master-1                  running (virtualbox)
master-2                  running (virtualbox)
master-3                  running (virtualbox)
node-1                    running (virtualbox)
node-2                    running (virtualbox)
```

I can do

```
vagrant ssh master-1
vagrant ssh master-2
vagrant ssh master-3
```

vagrant ssh-config shows

```
vagrant ssh-config
Host master-1
  HostName 127.0.0.1
  User vagrant
  Port 2206
  UserKnownHostsFile /dev/null
  StrictHostKeyChecking no
  PasswordAuthentication no
  IdentityFile /home/miki/.vagrant.d/insecure_private_key
  IdentitiesOnly yes
  LogLevel FATAL
```

But

```
ssh vagrant@192.168.1.8
vagrant@192.168.1.8: Permission denied (publickey).
```

fails.

I checked my id_rsa.pub

```
ssh-rsa 
AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAAACAQCZmhxzwwJJ1z/5rgoprHc31gneGY5rzFd/giE5ehZSH75WqT1hQKQ2gZUN8A3L+04oZ9H1uOUQHJBPV5mj7+FKkE+hPuTDVSUXcbYC9DlhurbmComoMh....oIQ== jovo@jovo-IdeaPad
```

and I can see that all five VMs have different authorized keys

```
ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAABIwAAAQEA6NF8iallvQVp22WDkTkyrtvp9eWW6A8YVr+kz4TjGYe7gHzIw+niNltGEFHzD8+v1I2YJ6oXevct1YeS0o9HZyN1Q9qgCgzUFtdOKLv6IedplqoPkcmF0aYet2PkEDo3MlTBckFXPITAMzF8dJSIFo9D8HfdOV0IAdx4O7PtixWKn5y2hMNG0zQPyUecp4pzC6kivAIhyfHilFR61RGL+GPXQ2MWZWFYbAGjyiYJnAmCP3NOTd0jMZEnDkbUvxhMmBYSdETk1rRgm+R4LOzFUGaHqHDLKLX+FIPKcF96hrucXzcWyLbIbEgE98OHlnVYCzRdK8jlqm8tehUc9c9WhQ== vagrant insecure public key
```

What should I do to enable ssh to all five hosts from my host?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I followed this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10864372/how-to-ssh-to-vagrant-without-actually-running-vagrant-ssh)

```
ssh vagrant@127.0.0.1 -p 2222 -o LogLevel=FATAL -o Compression=yes -o DSAAuthentication=yes -o IdentitiesOnly=yes -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -i /home/miki/.vagrant.d/insecure_private_key
```

I also found another solution by adding my id_rsa

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.ssh.insert_key = false
  config.ssh.private_key_path = ['~/.vagrant.d/insecure_private_key', '~/.ssh/id_rsa']
  config.vm.provision "file", source: "~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub", destination: "~/.ssh/authorized_keys"
  (1..3).each do |i|
    config.vm.define "master-#{i}" do |master|
      master.vm.box = "ubuntu/bionic64"
    end
  end
  (1..2).each do |i|
    config.vm.define "node-#{i}" do |node|
      node.vm.box = "ubuntu/bionic64"
    end
  end

  config.vm.network "public_network", :bridge => "wlo1"
  config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
    vb.memory = "3072"
    vb.cpus = "3"
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You do have to copy your public key whichis being Generated or you have to generate it with the command:-

Expecting Your Hostmachine is a linux machine

->ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096

The above command will create a public Key in

/home/user/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

Copy that public Key and you have to paste it in the vm machine to which you want to ssh, the path where to paste it is.

->/home/user/.ssh/authorized_keys

Paste the same public key in all the vm.this will make sure your host is haveing passwordless access to all the vm machines.

In some cases there is no file called as authorized_keys in the above path you do have to create the file at that time with the permission 700.

and the very last and main thing I saw in your Config File you have changed the Port number for SSH, So your command to connect with ssh should be like,

-> ssh -p 2206 vagrant@192.168.1.8

Some lil thing that i can do ..